# A single, common English word to describe moving an event up early

Tags: vocabulary

I am working on building active voice and concision in my writing style. I must describe an event that may be moved up early from its current scheduling. The only word found that describes this concept is "Prepone." Obviously, this isn't a common English word except in India apparently. Thank you.

Comment: Move up is quite common, but that's two words. Hasten has a slightly different connotation . Accelerate is similar to hasten and advance.

Answer (score 4):

Advance.

We have to advance this presentation or this other one won't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [Amadeus](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/26047/amadeus), it should be **advance**.
The fact remains that though the word may seem quite prosaic, it is quite technical in its usage.

It is further emphasized by [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/advance) definition of the word given by the Merriam-Webster dictionary. Look at the third entry for the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

## Upped:

As in, "We upped the date."

## Moved up:

Technically two words, but more precise than upped.

## Hasten:

"We hastened the schedule." It sounds slightly different, but could work.

## Accelerate:

"We accelerated the planned date." Similar to Hastened, the meaning is slightly different but workable.